# I keep getting an error and I know it's probably a simple mistake but I can't figure it out for the sake of me

Tags: java

I keep getting this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to int

whenever I go to compile my program. I just included my main since I don't think this has anything to do with the classes. Can someone please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;     

public class publicationMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out
                .println("Hi, welcome to the Publication Program. You will be required to     answer several questions about the ");
        System.out.print("publication(s):");
        System.out.println("How many publications would you like?");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = keyboard.nextInt();
        int test1;
        test1 = "b"; // this is where I'm having my problem!
        int i;
        int b, d, e, f;
        double c;
        publicationAbstract[] a = new publicationAbstract[x];
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("What is the the title of the publication?");
            b = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("What is price of the publication?");
            c = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out
                    .println("What is the publication year for this publication?");
            d = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Is this publication a Book(b) or a CD(c)?");
            e = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (test1 == e) {
                System.out.println("How many pages is the book?");
                f = keyboard.nextInt();
                a[i] = new publicationSub1(b, c, d, e, f);
                a[i].trans(c);
                a[i].getpublicationinfo();
                a[i].useMethod();
            } else {
                System.out.println("How many minutes are there in the book?");
                f = keyboard.nextInt();
                a[i] = new publicationSub2(b, c, d, e, f);
                a[i].trans(c);
                a[i].getpublicationinfo();
                a[i].useMethod();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm... yeah. You can't assign an `int` to a `String`. They're completely different types.

Comment: What `int` value would `"b"` represent and why?

Comment: You understand the Types right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say,

```
int test1;
test1="b";
```

You are saying that test1 is of integer primitive type, then you try and assign a String to it. That's obviously illegal. It isn't clear to me if you wanted

```
int test1 = (int) 'b';
```

or

```
String test1 = "b";
```

or even

```
int test1 = Integer.parseInt("b", 16); // <-- from hex.
```

Comment: For the hex example you could just do `int test1 = 0xb;`

Comment: @SamYonnou True, but that's not a String or char type.

Comment: Yes, but if OP was trying to assign a hex value to an integer they might have tried `test1 = "b"` after `test1 = b` failed. However from the rest of OP's code it seems like they probably want to read `String` and `char` values from the input stream but are reading `int` instead.

Answer (score 0):

test1 is an `int` but you're setting it equal to a string. "b" is not an integer.